# Borrar un registro en c++

Tags: c++

Estoy haciendo un ejercicio que consiste en crear varios registros y luego en el main dar la opción de añadir un registro nuevo, borrar uno o modificar, no consigo averiguar como eliminar un registro y como no me lo han explicado en clase la verdad es que ando un poco liado. Pongo aquí el código que he hecho hasta ahora, a ver si alguien me puede guiar un poco, muchas gracias de antemano!

```
//Elimina un registro que quiere el usuario
void bajaProducto(TProducto productos, int &num){
  int i, j;

  cout << "Introduce el producto que quiere eliminar: ";
  cin >> productos[i].nombre;

  if(i < num){        //Si encuentra el producto
                      //Hay que desplazar los registros
      if(i<num-1){    //No está en la última posición
          for(j = i; j < num-1; j++)
              productos[j] = productos[j+1];
      }
  num--;      //Se decrementa el contador de registros
  }else
      cout << "Producto no existe." << endl;
}
```

Comment: Este código no tiene el más mínimo sentido. La i no la inicializas, con lo que el if(i < num) te puede dar cualquier resultado. ¿Qué es TProducto? Parece un array. Y num? Así con este código no hay quién te ayude porque ni explicas lo que quieres ni lo que te pasa y el código no tiene sentido.

Comment: Si verdaderamente es un array, condidere remplazarlo con un `std::vector`.

Comment: Los ejemplos deben ser verificables. Poner cualquier cosa para que alguien más reescriba el código y te dé algo que funcione, es descortés y va contra las reglas del sitio

Answer (score 1, accepted):

De todos modos no podrás leer el nombre del elemento a borrar en cualquier elemento que existe ya. ¿Cómo puedes saber cual es el elemento correcto??? Necesitas una variable temporal para eso:

```
std::string name; // mejor solo utilizar nombres ingleses – de vez en cuando vas a presentar
                  // to codigo a personas no hispanohablantes, y ellos tienen que adivinar
                  // cual podría ser el objetivo – así podrán ayudarte solo con dificuldades...
std::cin >> name;
```

Ahora puedes buscar el elemento a borrar:

```
for(int i = 0; i < num; ++i)
{
    if(productos[i].nombre == name)
    {
        // encontrado - vamos a borrar!
        // (no debes comprobar si era el ultimo elemento:
        // en ese caso, simplemente no se entra al bucle...)
        for(++i; i < num; ++i)
            productos[i - 1] = productos[i];
        --num;
        return;
    }
}

// y si lleges aquí, no lo has encontrado...
```

Utilizando `std::vector` aun es mas fácil:

```
for(auto i = productos.begin(); i != productos.end(); ++i)
{
    if(i->nombre == name)
    {
        productos.erase(i);
        return;
    }
}

// no encontrado...
```